# JPA get foreign key without loading related record

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to optomize some reports and am trying to remove the need to load some expensive related records(multiple cascade loads, on each of ~500+ records).

My entity's are something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foo")
public class Foo
{
    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;
...
    public UUID getId(){
        return id;
    }
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bar")
public class Bar
{
    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="FOO_ID")
    private Foo foo;
...

    public UUID getFooId(){
        return foo.getId();
    }
```

My issue is that when i make this call: `return foo.getId();` hibernate goes and instantiates the Foo entity, and loads all related records even though i only want/need the id, which is a foreign key in my Bar table.

Is there any way to get Foo.Id from Bar without loading the Foo record?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to change `Foo.id` from property access (default) to field access. Also don't use `getFooId()` but `getFoo().getId()` to help Hibernate understand that you're actually accessing the `foo` reference as well as its ID.

Comment: @Thomas Correct me if i'm wrong here, but annotating with \@Id on a field makes this field access, right? (Sorry for the \, stackoverflow thinks i trying to notify another person)
And im not sure i understand your second point, could you send a code snippet?

Comment: I actually had the code snippet in the comment :) - `getFooId()` looks to Hibernate like there's a property "fooId". Instead use `getFoo()` to return the `foo` reference and then call `getId()` on that. Also `@Id` might make it field access now but it didn't a couple of years ago. So changing the access type might ne not be necessary anymore - I'd double check though.

Comment: @Thomas good catch. It needs just put `@Transient` on the getter.

Comment: @Thomas It can be a lot of weird errors, if mix property and field access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mapping the FOO_ID column as a basic mapping instead or in addition to the existing Foo reference mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bar")
public class Bar
{
    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="FOO_ID")
    private Foo foo;

    @Column(name="FOO_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private UUID fooId;
...

    public UUID getFooId(){
        return fooId;
    }
```

You can then decide to use fooId in queries to avoid joins. Because it is read-only, the FK value is still set from the foo reference - there may be some issues with a cache if you set the reference and not the fooId UUID; you can either set it yourself, or force a refresh to have JPA do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate thinks that `getFooId()` is a method that can potentially use any field of `Bar`. Hibernate can't check which fields exactly are used by the method, so it loads all lazy associations just in case.

You can use `@Transient` to avoid this

```java
@Transient
public UUID getFooId(){
    return foo.getId();
}
```